# Change list (.li and .ul) to roman numbers on jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css

How do I change control navigation to roman numbers, when I add

```
.evoslider .controlNav ul { 
  list-style: upper-roman; position: relative; 
}
```

I get double number roman and non roman number beside each other.

filmspecs.com/links.html

Comment: Where do you get the double roman and non roman number? Can you provide more code?

Comment: have a look at the link now .evoslider.default .controlNav ul 
{
 overflow: visible;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 list-style-type: upper-roman;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the roman numbers inside the `<li>` elements, and remove the `list-style` property from the CSSs.

I've looked around it but it looks like JavaScript is the only solution (if you cannot edit the source code). It's a bit tricky, but I've tested it on your site and works fine.

So try this JavaScript code:

```
Number.prototype.toRoman = function() {
    var digits = String(+this).split(""),
        key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM", "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC","","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
        roman = "",
        i = 3;

    while (i--) roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
    return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bullets').each(function(index, element) {
        element.textContent = (+element.textContent).toRoman();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to test it in the console of the browser you have to remove the `$(document).ready(` statement, obviously

Comment: @user3534336 then consider accepting my answer to close your question, so other people can find it easily

Answer (score 0):

It is showing both roman numbers and arabic numbers because in the `li` you have the numbers eg 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. You can remove those numbers and then you will only see the roman numbers.

Comment: li is generated automatically I cannot change it, it's coded into java script slider                                      <div id="mySlider" class="evoslider default"> <!-- start evo slider -->
     <dl>
     <dt>Spider</dt>
     <dd data-src="images/2-ALFA-ROMEOad.png" data-scale="fitImage" data-text="partialleft">
            <div class="evoText">
             <h3>Spec: Spider</h3>
             <p></p>
         </div>
         
     </dd>
    </dl>

</div> <!-- end evo slider -->